# MKTileOverlay, tiles at 180.0 / -180.0 not drawn consistenly

Tags: swift, mapkit, mktileoverlay

I used MKTileOverlay class to cover the map by self generated tile images.

All works good, except the tiles on the border at Longitude 180 or -180 degree. At this line, tiles are drawn only sometimes... can anybody give me a hint to solve that?

you can see the effect on this screenshot

[image]

This particular area of the map should be covered completely by this "default" tiles. The tile images itself should be OK, as they are displayed on the other tiles.

I use this loadTile(at: ... ) function to provide the generated tile images. The print statements shows that this function is called for all tiles and that the result function gets a valid image. It's just that the tiles are not drawn .. and I use the standard MKTileOverlayRenderer..

```
override func loadTile(at path: MKTileOverlayPath, result: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

    let x: Int = path.x
    let y: Int = path.y
    let zoomLevel : Int = path.z

    // calculate the x for the tile at longitude 180 degree
    let xMax = (1 << zoomLevel) - 1


    if (x == 0) || (x == xMax) {
        print("\(zoomLevel)/\(x)/\(y) requested")
    }

    // local variable to hold the image of the tile
    var localUIImage: UIImage = tileImageForDefaultImage


    // lots of stuff to generate the tile image


    // check if we have a valid image
    if let resultImage = localUIImage.pngData() {

        if (x == 0) || (x == xMax) {
            print("resultImage: \(resultImage.debugDescription)")
        }

        result(resultImage, nil )

    } else {

        let noResultImage = tileImageForDefaultImage.pngData()
        if (x == 0) || (x == xMax) {
            print("noResultImage: \(noResultImage.debugDescription)")
        }

        result(noResultImage, nil )
    }
}
```

.. any hint is welcomed ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: Apple confirmed that this is a bug in IOS MapKit. At least IOS versions 11 and 12 are affected. There is no known work around so far.

Long version: I spend a DTS ticket for this and got in contact with a really good Apple engineer. After some work together, he could easily reproduce the issue. He asked me to file a bug report (49270907). By this he was able to talk to the MapKit team and they confirmed the bug.

Comment: is this still an issue for iOS 13? Do you think this bug affects my question. I think it's similar if that both our questions don't seem to render visible tiles? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62824057/local-tiles-stored-in-sqlite-db-not-rendering-on-loadtileat-pathresult  Can you point me to the bug report? Thank you!

Comment: You are right. the bug is gone in IOS 13. The bug number is 49270907. But maybe it's already closed.